# Why am I unable to tracert to an IP on my desktop, but I can on my server?

Tags: static-routes

```
Desktop IP: 10.65.115.145
Server IP:  10.65.107.100
Local Core Switch: 10.65.0.1
Remote Core Switch: 10.64.0.1
Remote Server vLAN (sits in core switch): 10.64.30.1
Remote Server: 10.64.30.10
```

- I can ping and tracert from my local core switch to the remote server
  and remote server vlan.
- I cannot ping or tracert from my desktop to
  the remote server or remote server vlan.
- I can ping from my desktop
  to the remote core switch.
- I can ping and tracert from my server to
  the remote core switch and remote server.
- A tracert from my desktop
  to the remote server shows the hop dies at the remote core switch.
- A
  tracert from my server to the remote server shows it routes properly.
- A tracert from my local core switch to the remote server shows it
  routes properly.

I tested this from another system on the same vlan as my desktop and found I am unable to ping or tracert from the desktop's vlan; this is weird, since I can tracert all the way up to the remote core switch.

Does this mean the issue is on the remote end?  or is this an issue on the local end?

Comment: It implies the packets are getting to the remote server, and the remote server does not have a valid route to return them to your desktop IP range. But it does have valid routes back to the local core switch 10.65.0.1 and to the local server 10.65.107.100. What routes are involved on the remote server?

Comment: What are the subnet masks for each?  Are they all /16, or have they been broken down further?  Also, who is doing the routing?  The switches themselves, or are there more networking gear in between the switches?

Comment: Ok, I think I found the problem.  The static route on the remote end for the local desktop network is going through a different route than the route for the remote server, which would explain why it's not routing properly.  I'll need to test it tonight.